Datetimepicker: see whole month by default
I have a VB.Net Winforms app. One of the forms has a DateTimePicker control. By default, this control shows inline and closed, in about the same space as a textbox. I'd like the control to be opened by default when the form first opens, so the user can see the full month.
You can see what I mean here:

Is there a way to see the whole month without clicking on the arrow on the datetimepicker? How can I show this control open when the form loads?

Although the answers use C#, can you work from Open DateTimePicker C# control programmatically?
